# How to pass multiple search values to search.draw function in datatables?

Tags: jquery, search, datatables

I have multiple search options in my datatable. The below code is working for single search.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable();
    $('#filter').click(function(e){
    dataTable.search($("#txtSearch").val()).draw();});
} );
</script>
```

But i have multiple search text boxes/ listboxes. When user click on a Search Results button the table should draw the related search results. But how can i pass multiple search values to the search function ? Any help would greatly appreciated.
Multiple text boxes

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="3" style="width: 150px;">
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="12" style="width: 100px;" readonly="readonly">
<select id="13" class="form-control vcbot_search">
<option value="">ACKN Status</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id = "0" placeholder = "General Search">
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the multiple search text boxes? How exactly does it work? (you search for specific columns? You search for All of the values? or Any of them?

Comment: Please provide a *working example*. Put html+css+js code into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to show the problem.

Comment: jQuery('.vcbot_search').on( 'keyup change', function () {   
var i =jQuery(this).attr('id');  // getting column index
var v =jQuery(this).val();  // getting search input valuedataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
        } );

Comment: this code working fine for keyup or change event, but i need the search results when user click on a search button instead of keyup/ change with multiple search values.

Comment: Without a complete working example it's hard to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by using the below code.

```
<script>
 jQuery('#filter').click(function(e){
dataTable.columns(2).search(jQuery("#2").val()).columns(3).search(jQuery("#3").val()).columns(11).search(jQuery("#11").val()).columns(12).search(jQuery("#12").val()).columns(13).search(jQuery("#13").val()).draw();});
</script>
```

When user click on the filter button then only i am passing the search values to the draw function. It works fine for me.